# Inserting data to lookup field using rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

In alert I am getting value in `data.d.results[0](This is the value that I am getting from other list using rest).Subsystem.Title` and also if I use only title column then the value is inserted in the list but when I use a lookup column i.e. Subsystem, then it goes to error function.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://sharepoint.com/teams/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Features')/Items",
        type: "POST",
        data:  JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.FeaturesListItem' }, 
  'Title': data.d.results[0].Title,'Subsystem':data.d.results[0].Subsystem.Title}),
        headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(d) {alert("Items Inserted!"); 
        //window.location.href=referrer;    
        },
        error: function() {alert("Failed to Insert Items!");}
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between a Title column and a Lookup column?????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For lookup type column, the value will be `Integer` and must be the `ID` of Lookup `item`. In the request body, you have to specified it as

> InternalNameOfTheColumn + Id

Meaning that, If your column's internal name is `Subsystem`, in the request, it will be `SubsystemId`. Value of `SubsystemId` will be an `Integer` (Id of the lookup item).

```
JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.FeaturesListItem' }, 
  'Title': data.d.results[0].Title,'SubsystemId':"It will be integer"})
```

See more details, in my article.

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: How would  I know the ID for the items in the lookup column?

Comment: you can get IDs using another REST call. `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Name of the lookup list')/Items?$select=ID`

Comment: where do I need to call this again?

Comment: You have to make this call first to get all lookup ids. then you will make another call where `SubsystemId` will be one of the id from lookup ids.

Comment: m new to rest api, can u pls help me with an example code..

Comment: Then tell me your whole requirement

Comment: ...ur answers are always awesome!!