# Inserting lookup column using rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

The below code doesn't work just because of the lookup column. It is unable to insert items to the `list`..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#submit1').click(function(){
var idCount=0;
var filtervalue='';
var array=[1,2,3];

    var filterById = getFilter(array);                  
    function getFilter(ids) {
    var idFilter = "(ID eq ";
    var filter = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (i == ids.length - 1) {
            filter += idFilter + ids[i]+")";
        } else {
            filter += idFilter + ids[i] + ")"+ "or";
        }
    }
    return filter;
}                           
            $.ajax({
                url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Features')/Items?$filter="+filterById+"&$select=Title,Subsystem/Title&$expand=Subsystem/Title",
         type: "GET",    
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
for(var k=0;k<array.length;k++)
{

$.ajax({
        url: "https://example.com/teams/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Features')/Items",
        type: "POST",
        data:  JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.FeaturesListItem' }, 
  'Title': data.d.results[k].Title,'Subsystem': data.d.results[k].Subsystem}),
        headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(d) {
        alert("Items Inserted!"); 
        },
        error: function() {alert("Failed to Insert Items!");}
});
}
       },
        error: function (error) {
        alert("error");     
        }
    }); 
})

});
</script>
```

What should I do for this to work?

Comment: what is the internal name of the `Subsystem`?

Comment: Its same "Subsystem"

Comment: in GET request change the url like `"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Features')/Items?$filter="+filterById+"&$select=Title,Subsystem/ID,Subsystem/Title&$expand=Subsystem`. In the POST request change `data` like `JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.FeaturesListItem' }, 
  'Title': data.d.results[k].Title,'SubsystemId': data.d.results[k].Subsystem.ID})`. and feel welcome to give feedback on my last answers

Comment: Is it same for people and group column also?

Comment: Added as answer. If you People or Group column does not allow multiple selection, then it is the same. If it allows multiple selection, then it is different. You have to specify array of ID.  You will find everything here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31633/discussion-between-atish-dipongkor-and-vikash-kumar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the lookup item's ID to save new item. Need to change in the following blocks

In the `GET` request change the URL

```
 url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Features')/Items?$filter="+filterById+"&$select=Title,Subsystem/Title,Subsystem/ID&$expand=Subsystem"
```

In the `POST` request, change the request body

```
JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.FeaturesListItem' }, 
  'Title': data.d.results[k].Title,'SubsystemId': data.d.results[k].Subsystem.ID})
```

So why do you need to change? Read [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/162331/21421) for explanation.

Modified code looks like following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#submit1').click(function(){
var idCount=0;
var filtervalue='';
var array=[1,2,3];

    var filterById = getFilter(array);                  
    function getFilter(ids) {
    var idFilter = "(ID eq ";
    var filter = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (i == ids.length - 1) {
            filter += idFilter + ids[i]+")";
        } else {
            filter += idFilter + ids[i] + ")"+ "or";
        }
    }
    return filter;
}                           
            $.ajax({
                url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Features')/Items?$filter="+filterById+"&$select=Title,Subsystem/Title,Subsystem/ID&$expand=Subsystem",
         type: "GET",    
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
for(var k=0;k<array.length;k++)
{

$.ajax({
        url: "https://example.com/teams/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Features')/Items",
        type: "POST",
        data:  JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.FeaturesListItem' }, 
  'Title': data.d.results[k].Title,'Subsystem': data.d.results[k].Subsystem.ID}),
        headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(d) {
        alert("Items Inserted!"); 
        },
        error: function() {alert("Failed to Insert Items!");}
});
}
       },
        error: function (error) {
        alert("error");     
        }
    }); 
})

});
</script>
```